# ImageMagick - Convert XV/VIFF to BMP

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I would like to convert a Khoros Visualization Image – `.XV` or `.VIFF` extension – to bitmap. I've tried

```
convert tree.xv tree.bmp
```

but it returns a black image, while the original is similar to the following:

[image: convertion by ImageMagick] [image: How it should be]

I've looked into this [ImageMagick description](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_ImageMagick.htm) and it apparently supports this format:

> The ImageMagick utilities recognize the following image formats:
>
> `Name Mode  Description`
>
> `VIFF *rw+  Khoros Visualization image`

Is it possible to convert a `.XV` image to `.BMP` or `.PNG` using ImageMagick?

If someone would like to test, download an example of the [figure here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ypezedefrp0rx7j/tree_09_o.xv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was solving the same problem (probably on the same Brodatz dataset :-)). My solution was just using [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/).

While ImageMagick returned a black image (same problem as yours), the GraphicsMagick package worked good for me. The usage is very similiar, you just add `gm` at the beginning:

```
gm convert tree.xv tree.bmp
```

Answer (score 2):

The bug in ImageMagick will be fixed in version 6.8.7-0.

Comment: There is no link to this bug. I saw this post and fixed the problem in ImageMagick. Version 6.8.7-0 will be the next release and it will include this fix.